# Increment hours/minutes/seconds of date in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS using bash

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose todays' date is formatted to YYYYMMDDHHMMSS such as 20160720152654. I would want to add hours or minutes or seconds to date.

Add 1 hour should change date to 20160720162654
Add 1 minute should change date to 20160720152754
Add 1 second should change date to 20160720152655

This seems to give me incorrect results

d=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
pd=$(($d + ($d % (15 * 60))))
echo $d 
echo $pd

Output
20160720155141
20160720155482

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can manipulate input to pass it to `date -d`:

```
s='20160720162654'

# add 1 minute
date -d "${s:0:8} ${s:8:2}:${s:10:2}:${s:12:2} +1 min" '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'    
20160720112754

# add 1 sec
date -d "${s:0:8} ${s:8:2}:${s:10:2}:${s:12:2} +1 sec" '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'    
20160720112655

# add 1 hour
date -d "${s:0:8} ${s:8:2}:${s:10:2}:${s:12:2} +1 hour" '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'    
20160720122654
```

Comment: s=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
echo "Start Time" $s

e=`date -d "${s:0:8} ${s:8:2}:${s:10:2}:${s:12:2} +1 min" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
                                                                                                                      echo "End Time" $e                                                                                           Not able to get output. I get blank. TIA

Comment: `e=$(date -d "${s:0:8} ${s:8:2}:${s:10:2}:${s:12:2} +1 min" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"); echo "$e"` works for me

Comment: This does not work on a MAC.                                                           #!/bin/bash
e=$(date -d "${s:0:8} ${s:8:2}:${s:10:2}:${s:12:2} +1 min" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S");
echo "$e"                                                                                                             Error which I get is usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]

Comment: You will need gnu date for this. On my OSX I have it installed using home brew

Comment: This does the trick.                                                                                  e=`date -v"+1M" "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"`
echo $e

Comment: The `add 1 hour` to 20160720**16**2654` yields 20160720**12**2654.. That can't be correct? For better results try `date -d "+1 hour ${s:0:8} ${s:8:2}:${s:10:2}:${s:12:2}" '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'` which yields 20160720**17**2654.

Comment: To solve the timezone problem, you can add the `-u` option and add "UTC" to the given date: `date -u -d "${s:0:8} ${s:8:2}:${s:10:2}:${s:12:2} UTC +1 hour" '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`

Answer (score 2):

Minor addition to anubhava's answer:

Since the timezone info is not available in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS, you may get unexpected results depending on your actual timezone, such as:

```
s=20190201140000
date -d "${s:0:8} ${s:8:2}:${s:10:2}:${s:12:2} +1 minute" '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
20190201160100
# !? was expecting 20190201140100
```

As far as I could understand, this happens because of the `+1 minute` expression, which causes `date` to ignore your current timezone:

```
date
Thu Feb  7 17:07:28 +03 2019
date -d "20190207 17:07" "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
20190207170700
date -d "20190207 17:07 + 1 minute" "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
20190207190800
```

In my case, the timezone offset was +3, so that was causing problems:

```
date +%Z
+03
```

You should be able to make it work on all timezones, by adding the current timezone to the "-d" parameter:

```
s=20190201140000
date -d "${s:0:8} ${s:8:2}:${s:10:2}:${s:12:2} $(date +%Z) +1 minute" '+%Y%m%d%H%M'
20190201140100
```

Note 1 : All above commands are run on RHEL 7.4 & GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release

Note 2 : I am sure there must be an easier way :)

Comment: Good point about the timezone problem. "I am sure there must be an easier way" : yes, I think using `date`'s `-u` option to treat everything in UTC solves the problem.

Comment: it worked for me. why don't you put it in an individual answer so that I could vote for it? @mivk