# How to sum 2 hours to date column in csv file

Tags: bash, awk

I have csv file consist of 2 columns, name and date in 24 hours format

```
Name, log_date

John, 11/29/2017 23:00
```

And i want to add 2 hours to log date to change date and time to be as below

```
John, 11/30/2017 01:00
```

I tried to add it by below command but with no success

```
awk - F 'NR>1{$4+=(2/24);}1' OFS="," IN.csv > OUT.csv
```

I get the below output

```
2017.08
```

in values of the log date column

So please help

Comment: Should the date roll over also? i.e. If you add 2 hours to 23:00 should it be 01:00 of the next day? I ask this because from the attempt you've made this doesn't seem to be the requirement.

Comment: Thanks vasan, i updated it in the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increment hours/minutes/seconds of date in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491986/increment-hours-minutes-seconds-of-date-in-yyyymmddhhmmss-using-bash)

Comment: This is a nice question. But your try to solve the problem is inadequate. First analyze the problem and then post more adequate solution close to the problem.

Comment: @Joe I don't think this is a duplicate of the question you cited as this specifically mentions `awk`. Just that `bash` tag is there for more visibility.

Comment: @Joe my question is different from yours as i like to add 2 hours to all date columns values by awk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you're looking for is documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html).

Using space as a field separator :

```
{
     split($2,D,"/")
     split($3,H,":")
     # format for mktime is "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]"
     d = D[3] " " D[1] " " D[2]" " H[1] " " H[2] " 00"
     t=mktime(d)
     t = t + 7200 # add two hours
     $2 = strftime("%m/%d/%Y",t)
     $3 = strftime("%H:%M",t)
}1
```

Comment: Many thanks setop, this solution is working great after editing it 
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR>1{
split($2,N," ") #date and time is in one column delimited by space
split(N[1],D,"/")
split(N[2],H,":")
d = D[1] " " D[2] " " D[3]" " H[1] " " H [2] " 00" # format for mktime is "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]"
t=mktime(d)
t = t + 7200
$2 = strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M", t)
}1' IN.csv > OUT.csv

Answer (score 2):

You need a language that has datetime arithmetic. Perl for example:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -F'/,\s*/' -slane '
    $datetime = Time::Piece->strptime($F[1], $fmt);
    $F[1] = ($datetime + 7200)->strftime($fmt);
    print join ", ", @F
' -- -fmt="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" <<END
John, 11/29/2017 11:00
END
```

```
John, 11/29/2017 13:00
```

Given your input, there's no way to indicate that the time is 11 PM. How are you supposed to know that?

Comment: The time in 24 hours format, i don't perl language so it is hard for me to customize it to use it on csv file           can you add guidelines on the code to customize it on my file?

Answer (score 1):

below is oneliner in python. This is really not a useable code, but I believe you can get idea of using one-liners. This one-liner can be made yet simpler.

```
python -c "s=r'John, 11/29/2017 13:00'; 
print(s.replace(s.split(\" \")[-1].split(\":\")[0],str(int(s.split(\" \")[-1].split(\":\")[0])+2)));";
```

Output

```
John, 11/29/2017 15:00
```

Yet, this will not roll over the date like if 23+2 = 25 which should suppose to be 1:00

Comment: hmm :) I think `perl` or `python` is best solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F',' '{if(NR>1){printf("%s, ", $1);system("date -d \"+2 hours " $2 "\" +\"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M\"")}else{print $0}}' IN.csv > OUT.csv
```