# Foreach hour:min:sec.ms

Tags: bash

I would like to know how can I parse an foreach specifying hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds. Something like this:

```
DURATION=00:14:17.82 // (00 hours, 14 minutes, 17 seconds and 82ms)
for ((i=1;i<=DURATION;i++)); do
    // output the hour, minute, second and ms here
done
```

I want to iterate every milisecond, second, minute, hour! Like this:

```
00:14:17.82
00:14:17.83
00:14:17.84
00:14:17.85
...
00:14:18.01
00:14:18.02
...
01:00:10.15
01:00:10.16
01:00:10.17
...
```

I just know creating this for seconds and just seconds! But how can I make for hours, minutes, seconds and ms? Thank you so much!

Comment: Why does your example output go beyond the DURATION of 14 minutes?

Comment: Do you want to loop from `00:00:00.00` **until** `DURATION`, or are you trying to start from `DURATION`?

Comment: If I'm honest, this sound like an [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), especially the milliseconds part. If you could skip those then the `date` util could be enough as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38491986/increment-hours-minutes-seconds-of-date-in-yyyymmddhhmmss-using-bash?rq=1).

Comment: @JeffSchaller just example, the duration doesn't matter, just the format itself.

Comment: @0stone0 00:00:00.00 until duration

Comment: In addition to my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69382726/foreach-hourminsec-ms#comment122634310_69382726), a 'clock' that will write each **millisecond** to a file until the **14'th** minute is reached, will create a **11MB** file, not sure why you would want this... Please add some details.

Comment: Hello, I have already added all details, the file size doesn't matter, I just want to learn, I'm not facing X/Y problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** The following ideas assume a max `DURATION` of `23:59:59:99` or `24:00:00.00`; upper ranges can certainly be increased but keep in mind the extra overhead (cpu and/or memory) for brace expansions, especially if generating huge ranges that dwarf `DURATION` (ie, generating large volumes of timestamps that you'll never process).

---

If you're going to manually enter the value for `DURATION` then you could manually enter the following brace expansion series:

```
for i in {00..00}:{00..14}:{00..17}.{00..82}
do
    echo $i
done
```

**NOTE:** This relatively small set of of brace expansions was almost instantaneous and took up ~6 MB (RAM) on my system.

This generates:

```
00:00:00.00
00:00:00.01
00:00:00.02
00:00:00.03
00:00:00.04
... snip ...
00:14:17.78
00:14:17.79
00:14:17.80
00:14:17.81
00:14:17.82
```

---

Alternatively:

```
DURATION=00:14:17.82

for i in {00..23}:{00..59}:{00..59}.{00..99}
do
    [[ "${i}" > "${DURATION}" ]] && break
    # do other stuff
done
```

**NOTE:**

- on my system this took about about 10 seconds and 1.6 GB (RAM) to expand the series of brace expansions **before** the loop was processed
- this particular set of brace expansions creates 8.64 million timestamps but ...
- we break out of the loop after processing ~ 86K timestamps (or ~1% of the timestamps generated by the brace expansions) so ...
- we wasted a **lot** of cpu cycles and RAM generating timestamps that we never got around to using

---

Another idea is to write a 4-deep set of `for` loops and break out once we hit `00:14:17.82`, eg:

```
DURATION='00:14:17.82'

for a in {00..23}; do
    for b in {00..59}; do
        for c in {00..59}; do
            for d in {00..99}; do
                [[ "${a}:${b}:${c}.${d}" > "${DURATION}" ]] && break 4
                # do other stuff here
            done
        done
    done
done
```

**NOTE:** While each brace expansion is fast (and uses a miniscule amount of RAM), the nested/repeated expansions is going to eat up a lot of time the longer it takes to get to `${DURATION}`; however, unlike the previous ideas this one will at least let you start processing your timestamp values immediately, with intermittent (brief) delays as a new brace expansion is performed.

---

Of course we could just skip the brace expansion overhead and use 'normal' `for` loops, eg:

```
DURATION='00:14:17.82'

for ((a=0; a<=23; a++)); do
    for ((b=0; b<=59; b++)); do
       for ((c=0; c<=59; c++)); do
           for ((d=0; d<=99; d++)); do
                printf -v ts "%02d:%02d:%02d.%02d" ${a} ${b} ${c} ${d}
                [[ "${ts}" > "${DURATION}" ]] && break 4
                # do other stuff here
           done
       done
    done
done
```

**NOTES:**

- this eliminates the cpu/time/RAM overhead of the brace expansions
- assumes you have a newer version of `bash` that supports `printf -v`

---

And for the masochists:

```
DURATION='00:14:17.82'

for ((i=0; i<8640000; i++)); do

      hr=$(( ( i / 100 / 60 / 60 ) %  24 ))
     min=$(( ( i / 100 / 60 )      %  60 ))
     sec=$(( ( i / 100 )           %  60 ))
    msec=$((   i                   % 100 ))

    printf -v ts "%02d:%02d:%02d.%02d" ${hr} ${min} ${sec} ${msec}
    [[ "${ts}" > "${DURATION}" ]] && break
    # do other stuff
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over milliseconds and convert to the representation you want upon use. First, we write conversion functions:

```
millis_to_human() {
   local h m s ms
   # calculate all those hours, minutes, seconds...
   ((
      ms = $1,
      s = ms / 100,
      ms %= 100,
      m = s / 60,
      s %= 60,
      h = m / 60,
      h %= 60,
      1
   ))
   printf "%02d:%02d:%02d.%02d\n" "$h" "$m" "$s" "$ms"
}
human_to_millis() {
   # Match with regex
   [[ $1 =~ ([0-9]*):([0-9]*):([0-9]*).([0-9]*) ]]
   # Using 10# so that the number is always in base 10, even with leading 0.
   echo $(( ( (
      10#${BASH_REMATCH[1]} * 60 +
      10#${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ) * 60 +
      10#${BASH_REMATCH[3]} ) * 100 +
      10#${BASH_REMATCH[4]} ))
}
```

Then just:

```
duration='00:14:17.82'
duration_ms=$(human_to_millis "$duration")
for ((i = 1; i <= duration_ms; ++i)); do
   millis_to_human "$i"
done
```